# how can I install threadscope on Windows?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo, threadscope

Every effort of me following this https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope instruction and few others ways online resulted in failure. It would be great if someone can give me some insights about it.
This is my error:

```
> cabal install threadscope --minimize-conflict-set
```

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: threadscope-0.2.14 (user goal)
[__1] trying: cairo-0.13.8.1 (dependency of threadscope)
[__2] next goal: cairo:setup.Cabal (dependency of cairo)
[__2] rejecting: cairo:setup.Cabal-3.4.0.0/installed-3.4.0.0 (conflict: cairo
=> cairo:setup.Cabal>=1.24 && <3.3)
[__2] skipping: cairo:setup.Cabal-3.4.0.0 (has the same characteristics that 
caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=1.24 && <3.3' 
from 'cairo')
[__2] rejecting: cairo:setup.Cabal-3.2.1.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-3.2.0.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-3.0.2.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-3.0.1.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-3.0.0.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-2.4.1.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-2.4.0.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-2.2.0.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-2.0.1.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-2.0.0.2, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.24.2.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.24.0.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.8.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.7.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.6.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.5.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.4.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.3.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.2.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.1.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.1.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.22.0.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.4,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.3, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.2,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.20.0.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.7, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.6,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.5, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.4,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.3, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.2,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.1,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.18.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.3,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.2, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.16.0.1,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.16.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.14.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.12.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.10.2.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.10.1.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.10.0.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.6,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.4, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.8.0.2,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.3, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.2,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.6.0.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.2,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.4.0.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.2.4.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.2.3.0,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.2.2.0, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.2.1, cairo:setup.Cabal-1.1.6,
cairo:setup.Cabal-1.24.1.0 (constraint from minimum version of Cabal used by
Setup.hs requires >=3.4)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cairo, cairo:setup.Cabal)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cairo:setup.Cabal, cairo, threadscope
```

Answer (score 1):

Threadscope doesn't support the latest versions of GHC and cabal anymore. You could try installing cabal 3.2.0.0 and GHC 8.8.4, which I think should still be supported.

It might be easier to try the binaries from GitHub: https://github.com/haskell/ThreadScope/releases/tag/v0.2.14

Or alternatively, depending on what you want to profile, you might be able to use [`ghc-events-analyze`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-events-analyze) for which there is [a blog post here](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2014/02/ghc-events-analyze/). Or [`eventlog2html`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/eventlog2html) which was discussed in [this ZuriHac talk this year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ljv5FHGXDM).